# how to pass a variable from a template to the main php controller

Tags: php

it is an easy task to pass a variable from the php controller to a template.I just need to define a variable in the controller,and then when I use an `include` statement to direct the controller to a template,the variable is there and can be used in that template.The thing I want to do is that I want to define a variable in one of my templates,pass it to the controller,and then,the controller passes it to another template.What should I do?

Comment: This is really bad practice. Your views (templates) should never interact with your controllers, you'll end up with a terrible coding mess. Describe your scenario and why you want to do this and I'm sure we'll be able to help you out with a better solution to your problem.

Comment: ok.thanks for your answer.here is the problem.I want my users to fill a form,then see a confirmation page of what they just filled in the form inputs and then after confirming,the form data will go into the database.So I was thinking this way that first the form shows up and in the `action` part of the form,I'am gonna use `?confirm` to notify my controller that It needs to show the confirmation page.then I store the form values in some variables,and I can use them in a confirmation page template.but since the controller exits here,I have no access to the variables anymore.this was my thinking!